# Mysql in container or different VM

Tags: mysql, docker, virtual-machine, containers

I am running `MySQL` database on different VM (separate from web server).
Because of separate VM I can protect database by giving access permission to only server and closing all other ports other than 3306.

Now, with docker I can set up `LAMP` server in one container and `MySQL` in other. How secure and scalable is this solution?

I am not sure how this type of things work with container services!

Answer (score 0):

> protect database by giving access permission to only server and closing all other ports other than 3306.

You can do that with Docker containers. Take a look at [Docker Expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/expose).

Not sure what you mean by "scalable" here. See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/service-scaling/) for scaling containers in general. Usually it's not very difficult.

Comment: And is there any need of SSL in between containers? Coz we are using SSL to send data from one VM to other.